# Remove item from list flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, list

I have code using flutter, and have the following list

```
var data = [
      {
         'label' : '0.25x',
         'value' : '0.25'
       },
      {
         'label' : '1.0x',
         'value' : '1'
       },
      {
         'label' : '1.25x',
         'value' : '1.25'
       },
{
         'label' : '1.5x',
         'value' : '1.5'
       },
];
```

I want to delete the above data whose values are in this array

```
final removedData = [1.25, 1.5];
```

how can i delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `removeWhere`

```
data.removeWhere((data) => removedData.contains(data.value));
```

Comment: thank you, 
correct answer : data.removeWhere((data) => removedData.contains(data.value));

Answer (score 2):

```
data.map((e) => e['value']?.contains(removedData.toString())).toList();
```